# How to transform "aLengthMenu" values of dataTables into a PHP variable?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datatables

I use a dataTables table in my site with following configurations:

```
$('#search-table').dataTable({
    "dom": "<'box-content'<'col-md-4'l><'col-md-8 text-right'f><'clearfix'>>rt<'box-content'<'col-md-6'i><'col-md-6 text-right'p><'clearfix'>>",

    "aaSorting": [[ 6, "desc" ]],

    "aoColumnDefs": [
        { 'bSortable': false, 'aTargets': [ 7, 8 ] }
    ],

    "aLengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, 100, -1], [10, 25, 50, 100, "All"]],

    "iDisplayLength": 50,
    "pagingType": "full_numbers",

    "oLanguage": {
        "sSearch": 'Filter within results: ',
        "sLengthMenu": '_MENU_'
    }
});
```

I would like to know how I could get the value of "aLengthMenu" that is selected at the moment and save it as a PHP variable.

By default the first 50 lines of the table will be displayed as we can see at "iDisplayLength". Then we should have the possibility to get this number as a variable.

Then when the user changes the view to 10 (or 25, or 100, etc) the variable changes to the correspondent number.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: i am also using datatables. and when i change the length from 10 to 50 or some value, the post event is fired to the same source from which your grid was populated.
in that post you can see the posted parameter `iDisplayLength 50`.
maybe you can get your variable there.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is the `page.len()` API call that will allow you at anytime to see the page length.  http://datatables.net/reference/api/page.len()

I believe, but am not certain, that the `page` event is fired when the page length is changed. http://datatables.net/reference/event/page

You can write a method that listens for the page event and then finds out how many records are shown, then send that data off via AJAX to the server to be stored, or handled.

Simple example:

```
var table = $('#data-table').DataTable();
$('#data-table').on( 'page.dt', function(){
    var len = table.page.len();
    alert(len);
    //Sample Post
    //$.post('server.php',{len:len},function(){...});
});
```

**EDIT**
I feel I should mention that the dataTables version you are using is probably not current based on the option names you included.  The options changed to a more readable format fairly recently, but I believe the naming convention is still technically supported for the current version.  I would update the options though to the new names in case future releases of dataTables does not support the backwards compatability.